# Comparing two mySQl schemas

Tags: mysql

We are running an app on staging and production environments. We make changes to Staging DB tables as per testing results. Currently, I manually add changes to the tables in production.
Is there any way to compare the tables in staging and production and implement the changes to the schema with help of any tool?
**Update: I dont want to copy the data from staging to production, I only need to implement the changes to the schema (new columns added, any relationship added).**

Comment: you can use git to version your sql schema this will help you to easily manage what changes were made in which version

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL Workbench to check the differences. Check out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-database-diff-report.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating `migrations`

OR

1. Create a `db-schema` directory in your project folder
2. Add all db related changes in a new file, naming can be done based on table name and change or some other unique identifier
3. Now push changes to git every time
4. With this you could track your db related changes and according add those changes in production